# Can you help me test my regular expression for validating numbers between 0 - 24 with at most two decimal places?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I have an html form with a text input that I'm validating using a regular expression pattern.  I would like to restrict users to entering numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 24 (inclusive) with at most 2 decimal places.

We expect users to enter values like "2" or "4.75" or "23.5" although we would like not to fail validation if they enter a stupid but valid number like "3." or "005" or ".25" assuming we can parse it as a number.  Obviously (to me but apparently not to others who read this) a value like "1.2.3" or "abc123" would be invalid and should be rejected.

My regular expression is this:

```
^([0]*[0-9]|[0]*[1]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0]*[2]{1}[0-4]{1}|[.]{1}[0-9]{1,2}[0]*|[0]*[0-9]{1}[.]{1}[0-9]{0,2}[0]*|[0]*[1]{1}[0-9]{1}[.]{1}[0-9]{0,2}[0]*|[0]*[2]{1}[0-3]{1}[.]{1}[0-9]{0,2}[0]*|[0]*24[.]{1}[0]*)$
```

Here is an online tester you can try against:

```
https://regex101.com/r/bJ9hJ9/2
```

**Here is my question for the people that think I am being unclear:**

**I have run as many tests as I can think of - can you think of any more?**

- text containing text ("abc")
- single digit integers (1, 2, 3),
- double digit integers (15, 22, 89),
- more than double digits integer parts (334, 123123)
- numbers starting with a decimal (".4", ".9999")
- numbers ending with a decimal ("3.", "123123.")
- numbers with any amount of header or trailer zeroes (00000004.500000000)
- numbers with multiple decimals ("2...4", "3.2.1")
- ???

*(Yes, I know it's not the prettiest expression but it's working and I will be able to read it when I come back to it in six months without have to lookup regular expression rules...  I'm not looking for suggestions on how to reduce my expression or rewrite it unless you can come up with a problem case)*

Comment: Number with spaces as a divider (ie 1 250), numbers that uses comma as a decimal point (ie. 1,2), combination of the two.

Comment: This is where I would (optionally) validate the input as a number, then parse the number and use a range check..

Comment: What about multiple zeros? Is that valid? For instance: `00000000000000000000000000000000000000`. Btw, I think your question is off topic.

Comment: Make sure to put the relevant code (or regex a the case may be) in the question - the editor link is useful, but questions should "stand alone". I can't access said site, but I've formatted the question.

Comment: Given that your requirements are too unclear, it's impossible to tell whether your regex fails any cases. `-0` is a number which is >=0, but is rejected by your regex. `24.9` is a number which is >24, but is accepted by your regex. `1E1` is a number which is >=0 and <=24, but is rejected by your regex. Now for all of those and all the other corner cases you might say you don't care, or you might say you care and the current behaviour is correct, or you might say you care and the current behaviour is wrong. But it should be clear from your question what you're looking for. Right now, it's not.

Comment: In addition to what @hvd wrote, if these are times, then `0` and `24` could refer to the same time. Is that what you want?

Comment: You could sinplify your regex by removing `{1}` and the brackets around single digits and by introducing more groups, optional patterns... Something not ready - `^(0*(1?[0-9]|2[0-4])|[.][0-9]{1,2}0*|0*[0-9][.][0-9]{0,2}0*|0*1[0-9][.][0-9]{0,2}0*|0*2[0-3][.][0-9]{0,2}0*|0*24[.][0-9]{0,2}0*)$`, and still it will match numbers greater than 24.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, or perhaps I sholdn't have used the word "timesheet" in my question.  Obviously it misled you to think we were entering durations, not numbers.

In my scenario, users will be entering an amount of hours for example "I worked 3.75 hours on this task".  Not a duration with a ":".  I'm not concerned with localising the data to worry about "," instead of ".".  "0" hours means "I worked 0 hours".  "24" means I worked 24 hours.  If a user wants to type "00000003.5000000" then I will accept that rather then telling them they are an idiot.

Comment: @Laurel this really doesn't fit on CR. Asking people to test his code isn't on-topic on _any_ SE iirc. Also, Vogel has 14k+ rep on CR so that argument doesn't work.

Comment: @Laurel I think that refers to checking the code itself, not feeding in example input/outputs.

Comment: "24.9". Thanks @hvd for spotting that one.  To the rest of the comments/commenters that are too concerned about formatting and whether or not I am asking questions here properly... Wow.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```
^0*(?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?(?:\.[0-9]{0,2}|\.)?0*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Summary

This regular expression will do the following:

- allow numeric values only
- require the string to have at zero or one decimal point
- require the integer portion of the number to be a value equal to or between `0` to `24`
- require the decimal portion of the number to be a value equal to or between `.00` to `.99`
- allow any number of leading or trailing zeros
- allow a valid integer to be followed by a decimal point with no decimal number, i.e. `12.`
- allow the integer portion to be missing i.e. `.5`

## Examples

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/gX0hC7/2

**Sample Text**

```
a0.65
0.65
-0.65
-123.454
123.454
23
15
22
89
334
123123
.4
.9999
.9900
3.
123123.
00000004.500000000
2...4
3.2.1
```

**Sample Matches**

```
0.65
23
15
22
.4
.9900
3.
00000004.500000000
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  0*                       '0' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                        '1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    2                        '2'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-4]                    any character of: '0' to '4'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{0,2}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 0
                             and 2 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  0*                       '0' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Optional

The above expression will allow a null string.

If you also need to validate that the string does in fact contain a number then you can simply add a positive lookahead `(?=.*[0-9])` to ensure there is at least one digit.  Then the rest of the expression is identical.

```
^(?=.*?[0-9])0*(?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?(?:\.[0-9]{0,2}|\.)?0*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: What tool are you using to draw out the expression like that?

Comment: I'm using https://www.debuggex.com/ to generate the images. As you type your expression the site draws the image.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

It matches every valid time from 0:00 all the way up to 23:59 and nothing (I hope!) outside of that. If you would rather have a period (.) instead of the colon (:), just change it - you may need to escape it with a forward slash: `\.`

Comment: This is a nice answer however it matches `00:00` to `23:59`  which is different than `0:00`. to make it work for `0:00` you could change `0[0-9]` to `0?[0-9]`

Comment: @RoYoMi How do you get it to match `00:00`? See https://regex101.com/r/dQ2oU5/1

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking at validating numbers, not times/durations.  I've reworded my question.